# PHP Session Stopped Working

Tags: php, debugging, session

I've been using PHP sessions on a site I'm building and it's been working fine until strangely this morning:

One page one:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['myarray']=$myarray;
```

Then on page two I try:

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['myarray']);
```

however it shows an empty array.

I've checked on page 1 and the array has values in it.

Any ideas on what to look for to debug this?

Thanks.

(SOLVED): Eventually solved the problem - that  line has to be at the very top of each page where you use any session variables - literally line number 1!

Comment: What do you get when you use `print_r($_SESSION);` or `echo $_SESSION['myarray']`

Comment: Make sure that the session variable on the first page isn't being overwritten anywhere before you get to the second page and also, use var_dump on the $_SESSION at the end of the first page to make sure the session data is still there.

Comment: Hi, the variable isn't being overwritten as its set once right at the end. And when I do a var_dump on the second page i get array(0) { }
Whats odd is this was working 100% fine yesterday - since then I've only worked on modal view completely independent of the session code.

Comment: try removing session_start() on the second page. calling this starts a new session and variables saved before are overwitten

Comment: in your code on the first page, do you destroy the session?

Comment: No not destroyed anywhere. However have noticed one thing - the session IDs change between pages. I'm using session_start before the HTML tag on each page

Comment: It doesn't have to be the first line of code, but you have to do output buffering if something else is writing to the output before this. You should also enable logging of warnings as it will clearly tell you if output was already started.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have 'register_globals = On' on your php settings . I think this is the case. 
When you have register_globals  set on your php settings, then it will treat the

$_SESSION['myarray'] and $myarray as same.

Solution would be disable the register_globals in php as its deprecated in newer versions. 
Otherwise use different key name in $_SESSION variable or change $myarray variable to something different name.