# PHP Session IDS Vary

Tags: php, session

My sessions were working fine however today they are not.

I've debugging for last few hours to try and figure out whats wrong and I've noticed that the session_id() is different on each page - so my questions:

- I guess this is why my session variables are not being returned as expected. How do i rectify this?
- Why would it work yesterday (and last 7 days) but the issue occur now. I'm certain I've not changed any related code.

Thanks

(SOLVED): Eventually solved the problem - that  line has to be at the very top of each page where you use any session variables - literally line number 1!

Comment: I don't think sessions will vary day by day. Provide some code to get help from our large community.

Comment: Check the session options using `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572350/php-session-stopped-working